# Removing buffers of overlapping buffers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2, buffer

I work with ArcMap 10.2 and would like to remove buffers of the overlapping buffers, but not all overlapping buffers. So for example:

[image: Buffer Overlap]
I would like to remove the buffer in the middle and remain the outer two. I have many buffers though which overlap, I would do it for all of them, so I do not have to throw away all the overlapping buffers. I would like to use the ModelBuilder because I do not know much about Python.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [polygon neighbor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000045000000)s tools to have table with the neighbours. With this table, summary statistics gives you the numberof neighbours. buffers with two or more neighbors (or with a given overlap) need to be removed according to your example. this can be done using a select by attribute on the joined table.

Comment: When I remove the buffers with two or more neighbors I still have buffers with one neighbor which thus have an overlap (I do not want overlapping buffers though). But I would like to remove only one of the overlapping buffers, if they have an overlap..

Comment: you need an arbitrary decision rule in this case because it is symmetrical. A rule that is easy to implement is to select the buffers with one neighbour that have a smaller FID than their neighbour. This would provide a unique and robust solution.